# writing variables to a CSV file within a windows batch file/script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "drives=d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
SET "sourcedir=normal"
REM locate drive that has directory "?:\normal\f"
FOR %%d IN (%drives%) DO IF EXIST "%%d:\%sourcedir%\f\." SET "sourcedir=%%d:\%sourcedir%"&SET "destdir=%%d:\video"&GOTO founddrive
ECHO Could not find "%sourcedir%\f" on any drive
GOTO :eof

:founddrive
SET /a destnum=1
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
    'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\f\*.TS"'
) DO (
    MD "%destdir%!destnum!" 2>NUL
    SET "filename=%%~na"
    SET "filename=!filename:~0,-1!R%%~xa"
    MOVE /y "%sourcedir%\F\%%a" "%destdir%!destnum!\video.MP4"
    MOVE /y "%sourcedir%\R\!filename!" "%destdir%!destnum!\video2.MP4"
    For /f "Tokens=1,2 Delims= " %%A in ('dir /T:C "%destdir%!destnum!\video.MP4" ^| Find /I "%destdir%!destnum!\video.MP4"') Do Echo " Starting Date,%%A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, ">>%destdir%!destnum!\info.csv
    For /f "Tokens=1,2 Delims= " %%A in ('dir /T:C "%destdir%!destnum!\video.MP4" ^| Find /I "%destdir%!destnum!\video.MP4"') Do Echo " Starting Time,%%B,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, ">>%destdir%!destnum!\info.csv
    SET /a destnum+=1
)
```

thanks to @Magoo for helping with the core of this script. i found i need to do 1 more task and generate a CSV file with the date and time. where i am stuck is with

this creates info.csv but gives me 2 lines in the correct directory but the inf.csv file is not formatted as a proper CSV. everything but the variables are in 1 cell comma's included.

```
Do Echo " Starting Date,%%A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, ">>%destdir%!destnum!\info.csv
```

if i remove the quotes the whole script bombs out

```
Do Echo Starting Date,%%A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,>>%destdir%!destnum!\info.csv
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: try `... Do Echo Starting Date,"%%A",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,>> ...`

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. It shouldn't.

`dir /T:C "%destdir%!destnum!\video.MP4"` output should not contain the string `"%destdir%!destnum!\video.MP4"` so no matches should be found, hence neither `echo` should occur. Now `video.mp4` is far more likely to generate a hit.

So, to generate the `.csv`, try

```dos
 For /f "Tokens=1,2 Delims= " %%A in ('dir /T:C "%destdir%!destnum!\video.MP4" ^| Find /I "video.MP4"') Do (
  Echo "Starting Date","%%A",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
  Echo "Starting Time","%%B",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
  )>"%destdir%!destnum!\info.csv"
```

Note that there's no point in running `dir` twice. The syntax `(...)>filename` will create a new file `filename` containing the output-to-console from any commands between the parentheses. Use `>>` to append to any existing `filename` if desired.

Personally, I'd establish a variable which I'll arbitrarily and for no particular reason call `commas` containing a long string of potatoes and then replace the comma-sequence in the `echo`es with `%commas:~-x%` where `x` is the number of commas required. Saves going cross-eyed counting the little perishers, especially if there's a need to change the count.

Comment: i added your suggested code and the batch file would blink then exit with no acctions. i removed the quotes from the last line )>"%destdir%!destnum!\info.csv" and BOOM it worked. the commas were from opening the CSV file with a text editor. there are a few more lines that need to be created that fill more cells but i removed them for clarity of my question.  ill experiment with %commas:~-x% to see how that works.

thank you, you are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Removing those quotes *should* have absolutely no effect whatever on how the code works - they were there to cater for spaces in names. I'd suggest that perhaps the quotes had become "smart quotes" or WP-style inverted commas (I'd have referred to them as `66` and `99`). Regardless, when you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will often close if a syntax-error is found. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any error message will be displayed.